# How to use Predicate String for Child / Parent / Sibiling elements for XCUITest

Tags: appium, xcuitest

Appium taking more time (around 240 sec) to perform the operations with XPATH.

Ex:

```
XPATH: //XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="Program"]/../following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther
```

So is there any other way to perform the operations on this element with lesser time? Can we use Predicate String strategy for this type of Xpaths?

Below is my environment:

> XCODE Version: 9.1
>
> Appium version: 1.7.2-beta2
>
> iOS version: 11.1

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is the slowest way to find an element.

To find nested elements, you can search like this (example in ruby):

```
(find_element(:name, 'Program')).find_element(:class, 'XCUIElementTypeOther')
```